# How to open an image with Krita from within Blender on PopOS?

Tags: external-applications

I am trying to open an image with Krita from within Blender on PopOS.
I know on windows you can apparently just point to the .exe, but what to point to on Linux?

I tried `/usr/bin/krita` and `/usr/share/krita`, but without successs.

[image]

Whenever I shift-click on the folder icon of an image datablock in Blender, it opens the default Linux image viewer.
When I install the flatpak version of Krita I am even more lost what to put in the Application field in the File Paths section of the User Preferences.
Does anyone know how to get it to work in PopOS (or Ubunutu, I guess)?

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu it works fine if krita or gimp are install via deb. use the path usr/bin/krita or usr/bin/gimp
They open as if there where blender windows.
[image: gimp and krita open as blender windows]